# Topics with more visit first

Tags: mysql

I have a column called `visitas` = varchar(20).

What I want is to select the topics with more visits in the last 3 days, putting first the ones with more visits, so I tried:

```
SELECT titulo, id, visitas from posts where data >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 3 day) order by visitas desc limit 10
```

but the `order by visitas desc` is not working as I want, it is not ordering topics with more visitors first...

```
topic1 title 2(visits)
topic2 title 2(visits)
topic3 title 10(visits)
topic4 title 1(visits)
```

What do I need to change?
thank you friends!

Comment: Can you give us an example of the output you're getting?

Comment: Why do you have the count of visitors in a `varchar` field instead of `int`?

Comment: topic1 title - 2(visits) ; topic2 title 2(visits) ; topic3 title 10(visits) -> topic3 should be the first one... If I change it to int will it work?

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the column to `INT`. Integers are compared numerically, strings are compared lexicographically. So the string `'10'` is lower than `'2'` because it just compares it character by character.

If you can't change the datatype, you can convert it in the query

```
ORDER BY CAST(visitas AS DECIMAL) DESC
```